# Need to install i386-linux-gnu libs on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, system-installation, upgrade, dpkg, 32-bit

I'm struggling to install i386 packages on my ubunutu 18.04 system. I tried following commands but nothing happened.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt -get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install libglib-2.0-0:i386
```

The highlighted packages are not available in my system. I need those packages to install in my system

**/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0**

**/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.4**

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.4

Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please include each command you tried along with the complete unredacted output of each command. You should use backticks to retain line breaks and monospace formatting so that we can parse the information.

Comment: Which application needs 5600.4? There are no official packages with [such glib files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libglib-2.0.so&searchon=contents).

Comment: `libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.4` is glib2 version 2.56.4 which was never used in Ubuntu http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib2.0/